Convergence in $L^{p}$ and convergence of derivative
Suppose $f_{n} \to 0$ strongly in $L^{p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ for some $p \in [1, \infty]$, where $f_{n}$ is a smooth sequence. Is it true that $f_{n}' \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in the sense of measures, i.e. that for any $\phi \in C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ and compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ \int_{K}  \phi f_{n}'~dx \to 0 ~?$$
Of course, we can say that $f_{n}' \to 0$ in sense of distributions but I am trying to upgrade this convergence to the above sense. Perhaps there is a clever density argument we can use? Formally I think the result should hold but I am not sure how to prove it.
Thank you!

$\varphi \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ or $\varphi \in C_0(K)$?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend $\varphi \in C_{0}(K)$ i think

Then you can approximate $\varphi$ by $C_0^\infty(K)$ functions and integrate by parts.

This is not true, since we can take a non-zero $f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and define $f_n(x)=n^{1/2}f(nx)$. Then, it follows that $$\lVert f_n \rVert_1=n^{-1/2}\lVert f \rVert_1 \to 0, $$
while
$$ \lVert f_n' \rVert_1=n^{1/2}\lVert f' \rVert_1 \to \infty.$$ Hence, $f_n' \not\rightharpoonup 0$ in the sense of measures, since that would imply boundedness of the $L^1$-norms.

Do you mean $|f'|_{1}$ on the second line?

Yes, that was a typo, I fixed it
